# iOS WkWeb doesn't allow access to HttpOnly cookies

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I believe I know the answer, but I just want to confirm I haven't missed anything.  We have a web page where we want to pass a ***HttpOnly*** cookie back to the native code from the WkWebView.  I have tried everything I can think of, but it won't let me see those.  I can pass values into WkWebView by adding it to a request.

My guess is that Apple is afraid that someone will write an App that loads other peoples websites and scrapes the HttpOnly cookies from the site and use them for evil.  But it kills those of us who have a legitimate need.

Comment: Yep, there is no way to access http-only cookies directly at this moment for `WKWebView`, you don't miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see HttpOnly cookies via WKHTTPCookieStore. Works in iOS 14.0.